# How to change an input value of type button to lowercase on button click

Tags: java, html, button, onclick

Let's say I have 5 of these

```
<input type="button" class="button" value="A">

<input type="button" class="button" value="B">

<input type="button" class="button" value="C">

<input type="button" class="button" value="D">

<input type="button" class="button" value="E">
```

So basically I want all the buttons with a class of  **button** to change its value from uppercase (A) to lowercase (a) when I click on a specific button like this
`<input type="button" id="ChangeBtn">`

I tried using JavaScript (which im new to) to do this.

```
<script>

//The button I want to click to perform the function

Var button = document.gelementById("ChangeBtn");

//The buttons with a class button I want to change its value to lowercase

Var value = document.querySelector(".button").value;

button.onclick = function (){

Value.classList.toggle("change");

}

</script>
```

Using the class list

```
.change{

text-transform : lowercase

}
```

Comment: `querySelector()` only selects one element. You want to use `querySelectorAll()`. Also you want to change the class of the HTML elements and not their values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to use `document.querySelectorAll` to access multiple elements. Then Array will be created.

```
var buttonArray = document.querySelectorAll(".button");


for(btn in buttonArray){
    btn.addEventListener("click", function(){
        //action that will happen after click
    });

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
you can use this code example:
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
  
    <input type="button" onclick="Lowercase();" value="Change Letters" />
    <input type="button" class="button" value="A" />
    <input type="button" class="button" value="B" />
    <input type="button" class="button" value="C" />
    <input type="button" class="button" value="D" />
    <input type="button" class="button" value="E" />

    <script>
      function Lowercase() {

        const nodeList = document.querySelectorAll(".button");
        for (let i = 0; i < nodeList.length; i++) {
          nodeList[i].style.textTransform = "lowercase";
        }
      }
   
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you bro I tried it and it worked what if I want to change it back like a toggle